# Text wrap not creating vertical separation lines tabular with m{2cm}

Tags: tables, arrays, multirow, multicolumn, wrap

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}% Not sure what this is for
 \usepackage{array,ltablex,makecell}% ltablex loads tabularx and longtable also
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
% \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}%This is for descriptions to appear on the LHS with an indent
\newenvironment{conditions}
 {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
 {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}%This is for descriptions of equations
\usepackage[]{multirow}%Essential for cells in table spanning multiple rows
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}% This is for quotes
% \usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}% This is formatting for long tables
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}%This is a wrapper to make everything a certain width -left aligned columns with stuff at the top.
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%This is a wrapper to make everything a certain width -left aligned columns with stuff at the top.
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned, p puts stuff at the bottom, m middles everything.
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned.
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
% \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%This is to force new lines in cells
\usepackage{graphicx}% This is for images
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}%This is for precision tables per property
% \captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false} % optional, this makes the caption numbers appear on a new line.
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{small}
\centering
\ra{1.0}
\begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}|c|c|c||c|c|c|}
\cline{3-8}
& & \multicolumn{3}{ c|| }{Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{Test Set 2} \\\cline{3-8} 
& & Precision & Recall & F1 & Precision & Recall & F1 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |m{2cm}}
{\multirow{8}{2cm}{Distantly Supervised Models} } 
&
\multicolumn{1}{ |m{4cm}| }{No APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold} & 
3 & 2 & 0 & 1 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{2-8}
&
\multicolumn{1}{ |m{4cm}| }{No APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold} & 
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{2-8}
&
\multicolumn{1}{ |m{4cm}| }{APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold} & 
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{2-8}
&
\multicolumn{1}{ |m{4cm}| }{APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold} & 
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{1-8}
\end{tabular}
\end{small}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Adapted from here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Which results in:

[image]

Why is the first column not leading to a full vertical line to the left?

Comment: Please complete this to a compilable example, not just a fragment of code. Why did you tag it with [tag:tabulary]? You're not using its features in this table

Comment: There wasn't a `tabular` tag.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati: Read the [description](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tables/info) related to the [tag:tables]...

Comment: Understood - sorry! Retagging this.

Comment: **Are you really still not sure what the first line of your code is for? If so, *please read a basic introduction to LaTeX before proceeding any further*.** Doing so will save you a world of pain and senseless frustration.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer its for a thesis type document, which this is for.

Comment: Can you send me a link that explains why a `report` shouldn't contain a table? Are you saying I should change to an `article`?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati: I know what `tabulary` is used for  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't present a table like this for reasons which I believe have been explained in answers to your previous questions. However, if you must, then you want something like this in which

```
{|m{2cm}|m{4cm}|c|c|c||c|c|c|}
```

gives the default specifications for columns. Notice that this way, you only need 2 exceptions to adjust the vertical rules for the first two rows. (You could make do with one - two just seemed easier.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \small
  \centering
  \ra{1.0}
  \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{4cm}|c|c|c||c|c|c|}
    \cline{3-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{ c|| }{Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{Test Set 2} \\\cline{3-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & Precision & Recall & F1 & Precision & Recall & F1 \\ \hline
    \multirow{8}{2cm}{Distantly Supervised Models}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    3 & 2 & 0 & 1 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{2-8}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{2-8}
    &
    APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{2-8}
    &
    APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \cline{1-8}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted, but ugly, table]

## EDIT

Bernard's suggestion is to use `hhline` to make the table a little less ... well, to make it a little better. I've only ever used this for examples here and, since I would not present my own tables this way, I don't know if this is the most effective way to use it or not or not.

But here's an example.

[image: slightly less hideous table, possibly]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array,hhline}
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \small
  \centering
  \ra{1.0}
  \begin{tabular}{||m{2cm}|m{4cm}||c|c|c||c|c|c||}
    \hhline{~~|t:*{3}{=}:t:*{3}{=}:t|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c||}{} & \multicolumn{3}{ c|| }{Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{3}{ c|| }{Test Set 2} \\\hhline{~~||---||---||}
    \multicolumn{2}{c||}{} & Precision & Recall & F1 & Precision & Recall & F1 \\ \hhline{|t:==:|-|-|-||-|-|-||}
    \multirow{8}{2cm}{Distantly Supervised Models}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    3 & 2 & 0 & 1 &  2 & 3  \\ \hhline{||~-||---||---||}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \hhline{||~-||---||---||}
    &
    APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \hhline{||~-||---||---||}
    &
    APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &  2 & 3  \\ \hhline{|b:==:b:*{3}{=}:b:*{3}{=}:b|}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe using `hhline` would improve a little?

Comment: Thank you, I see what this is doing now. @cfr please let me know about the report aspect, I am not sure about this even though I have tried to read the documentation, it says a `report` is for a thesis which is what this is for.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati So what aren't you sure about? This is a standard class.

Comment: Why are you saying I shouldn't have tables in a report class?

Comment: @Bernard Possibly. Anywhere in particular? Double lines seem especially problematic to me. (Especially the double vertical.)

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Where did I ever say that?

Comment: Ahhh ok you were referring to the comment I put for myself. Don't worry I know what it is, the report is 150 pages long so is the least of my worries to clean up comments. Especially with your answers I have learnt all I've ever known about Latex.

Comment: @Bernard Oh, I see. Give me a minute. I've never used this before!

Comment: @DhruvGhulati ***Then please remove the comments from code you post.*** You waste everybody's time posting stuff irrelevant to the question. What you do in the privacy of your own source code is your business, of course. But there is no need to inflict it on an unsuspecting public ;).

Comment: @Bernard Like this? I'm not always sure how to do it as this seems much less logical than using `booktabs` or `makecell` 's approaches.

Comment: @cfr: Not bad at all, albeit  'twas not exactly what I had in mind. I'll show you in a moment a layout that' more… less (or is it less more?).

Comment: @Bernard If you mean less is more, you're preaching to the choir. I would NOT use this myself! But the OP has asked multiple table questions and received all the usual suggestions, but evidently wants non-professional-looking tables. (Or has submission guidelines which force the use of such tables.)

Comment: Both, I've changed my table and it looks a awesome with this book table stuff. Will show you when I get a chance !

Answer (score 1):

Here are three more variations on the use of `hhline` – and, naturally, quite a few other packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry} \usepackage{array}
\usepackage[]{multirow, graphicx, hhline, rotating, makecell, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \small
  \centering\setlength\doublerulesep{5pt}
  \ra{1.0}
  \begin{tabular}{c|S{m{4cm}}||c|c|c||c|c|c|

}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{ c }{\sffamily Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{3}{ c}{\sffamily Test Set 2} \\%
     \hhline{~~|---||---}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & Precision & Recall & F1 & Precision & Recall & F1 \\
     \hhline{~|-||---||---}
    \multirowcell{8}[10pt]{\rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\sffamily Distantly Supervised Models}}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ %
    \hhline{~|-||---||---}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\ %
    \hhline{~|-||---||---} & APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
\hhline{~-||---||---}
    &
    APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
     \hhline{~-||---||---}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \small\
  \centering\setlength\doublerulesep{5pt}
  \ra{1.0}\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|m{4cm}||c|c|c||c|c|c|}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\sffamily \multirowcell{2}{Distantly Supervised \\Models}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\sffamily Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\sffamily Test Set 2} \\%
     \hhline{|~||---||---}
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& Precision & Recall & F1 & Precision & Recall & F1 \\
     \hhline{-||---||---}%
      No APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ %
    \hhline{-||---||---}

    No APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\ %
    \hhline{-||---||---}
     APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
\hhline{-||---||---}

    APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
     \hhline{-||---||---}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \small
  \centering\setlength\doublerulesep{5pt}
  \ra{1.0}
  \begin{tabular}{c|S{m{4cm}}||c|c|c||c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{ c }{\sffamily Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{3}{ c}{\sffamily Test Set 2} \\%
     \hhline{~~|---||---}
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{@{}l|}{\sffamily Models} & Precision & Recall & F1 & Precision & Recall & F1 \\
     \hhline{~|-||---||---}
    \multirowcell{6}[10pt]{\rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\sffamily Distantly Supervised}}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ %
    \hhline{~|-||---||---}
    &
    No APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\ %
    \hhline{~|-||---||---} & APE Threshold w/o Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
\hhline{~-||---||---}
    &
    APE Threshold w/ Probability Threshold &
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
     \hhline{~-||---||---}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]